# Java enum error - return type reqiued

Tags: java, enums

I created simple enum class in java.

```
public enum XmlElementsInput {

    element_sentenceInput("a");
    element_sentence("b");

     private final String elementName;

    private XmlElementsInput(String name) {
        this.elementName = name;
    }
    public String getElementName() {
        return elementName;
    }
}
```

But Netbeans say me: `invalid method declaration; return type required, ilegal start of type` on line `element_sentence("b");`. I dont know why? Can you tell me why?

Comment: Aside from anything else, you should follow Java naming conventions. I'd call those enum values `SENTENCE_INPUT` and `SENTENCE`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The `enum` types must separated by comma:

```
element_sentenceInput("a"),
element_sentence("b");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use commas to separate enum values, as follows:

```
public enum XmlElementsInput {

    element_sentenceInput("a"),
    element_sentence("b");

    // Remaining part
}
```